# Load Ionic Page from Native View Controller

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have to replace the main screen of an app done in Ionic with a native one and from it navigate (push/show) different Ionic pages. How can I transition to Ionics web view and specify what page it should load from a native VC.

Thanks.
J.